# Trouble producing discrete legend using ggplot for a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I am fairly new to the ggplot function in R. Currently, I am struggling to produce a legend for a given data set that I have constructed by hand. For simplicity, suppose this was my data set:

```
rawdata<-data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,
                             2,1,-1,
                             3,-1,-1,
                             4,-1,1
                             4,-2,2),5,3,byrow=TRUE))
names(rawdata)<-c("Town","x-coordinate","y-coordinate")
rawdata[,1]<-as.factor(rawdata[,1])
```

Now, using ggplot, I am trying to figure out how to produce a legend on a scatterplot. So far I have done the following:

```
p1<-ggplot(data=rawdata,aes(x=x.coordinate,y=y.coordinate,fill=rawdata[,1]))
+geom_point(data=rawdata,aes(x=x.coordinate,y=y.coordinate))
```

I produce the following using the above code,

[As you can see, the coordinates have been plotted and the legend has been constructed, but they are only colored black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5n71.png)

I learned that to color coordinates, I would have needed to use the argument `colour=rawdata[,1]` in the `geom_point` function to color in points. However, when I try this, I get the following error code:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): colour
```

I understand that this has something to do with the length of the vector, but as of right now, I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this small problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_point()` takes a `colour`, not a `fill`. And, having passed the data into `ggplot(data = ..)`, there's no need to then pass it into the `geom_point()` again.

I've also fixed an error in the creation of your `df` in your example.

```
rawdata<-data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,1,-1,3,-1,-1,4,-1,1,4,-2,2),5,3,byrow=TRUE))
names(rawdata)<-c("Town","x.coordinate","y.coordinate")
rawdata[,1]<-as.factor(rawdata[,1])


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=rawdata,aes(x=x.coordinate,y=y.coordinate,colour=Town)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Comment: beautiful! Thank you very much for your very quick response. This has helped me a lot!

Comment: @tinder No problem. If this answer solves your question you should press the 'tick' icon below the voting arrows to show the solution has been accepted.